# Revert Windows 10 File Explorer to Previous Behaviour

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search, file-search, windows-10-v1909

Windows 10 Version 1909 introduced a new feature in File Explorer.

Previously, when you searched in a File Explorer window, the contents of that folder/window would automatically change along with your typing to only show files that match your search.

However, as described in [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/437112/whats-new-in-windows-10s-19h2-update-arriving-fall-2019/) How-To-Geek article, since version 1909, when you type in the search box it shows a drop-down menu with suggestions from your PC and from online accounts, but doesn't change the contents of the folder to reflect your typing, you have to press enter for that to happen.

Does anybody know of a registry hack or other trick to revert this change. Basically, I don't mind the drop-down menu, but I urgently need the contents to change automatically to reflect the typing in the search box, while typing - like it used to be before this update - without having to press enter. I work with loads of files constantly,  and this is a critical feature for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to populate as I go and then un-populate as I complete. I have to type slowly to see this and if I type fast I just get the result. That is the new Explorer functionality and so we must adapt. I have to say it works for me.

Comment: Or use a third-party alternative to Windows Explorerhttps://alternativeto.net/software/windows-explorer/